# Spring RequestMapping using PathVariable results in 404

Tags: spring, http

I have a spring application and I can't solve a problem. When I use a `PathVariable`, the value in my `RequestMapping` is getting added to the URI and the `DispatchHandler` is getting confused.

For example, when I request `/Dashboard/project/1131/`

I get `HTTP Status 404 - /Dashboard/project/1131/WEB-INF/jsp/projectDetail.jsp`

The project/1131 gets added into the path for some reason

When I request `/Dashboard/projects` Spring finds my .jsp and presents it. /`project/{projectId}` doesn't work - I get the behavior described above.

Here's my controller

```
@Controller
public class ProjectController {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@RequestMapping(value = "projects", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String projects() {
    return "/projects";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/project/{projectId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String project(@PathVariable("projectId") String projectId, ModelMap map) {
    map.put("projectId", projectId);
    logger.info("Project Id: " + projectId);
    return "/projectDetail";
}

}
```

My configuration

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<!-- Webapp name -->
<display-name>Dashboard</display-name>

<!-- default file name -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- spring listener (all spring jars need to be in WEB-INF/lib -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- set servlet to DispatcherService -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dashboard</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- hand all requests to dispatcher service -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dashboard</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

AppConfig

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

}
```

dashboard-servlet.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- the packages to scan for annotations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dennisstevens.dashboard.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dennisstevens.dashboard" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dennisstevens.dashboard.domain" />

<!-- Tell Spring that MVC components are @Annotation Driven -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Tell Spring Dispatch Handler to look in WebContent/resources/ for resources -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Tell Spring to scan for config annotations -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!--  TODO: Figure out how to load this in AppConfig -->
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

This has to be simple - but I have looked through the documentation and searched the internet for hours. It looks like I am doing everything right from what I can see.

Comment: Unrelated, but why use a 2.5 schema with a 3.0 app?

Comment: Thanks. I started with a 2.5 example and didn't clean up that reference. I will clean that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think having a leading slash in `resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");` should fix it for you.

Comment: Except I am not finding resources now either. No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Dashboard/projects/resources/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dashboard'. In this case, I do have the leading slash in front of resources.

Comment: I fixed that too. I have to use c:url to make absolute paths. <script src="<c:url value = "/resources/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" />">